# Subclassing weird behavior in CircuitPython

Tags: micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

###### Some background:

In *MicroPython* there is a class called *Pin* which controls I/O pins. In *CircuitPython* a similar class is called DigitalInOut. So for compatibility I wrote this simple class. Unfortunately, something goes wrong with my implementation. after calling:

```
drv_enn = PinC(board.D0, PinC.OUT)
drv_enn.on()
```

the pin doesn't go into 3.3V, but rather into 3.51V, which seem to be the uninitialized value. but this code **does work**, taking the pin into 3.3V:

```
drv_enn = DigitalInOut(board.D0)
drv_enn.direction = Direction.OUTPUT
drv_enn.value = True
```

so when I implemented a class without inheritance, it worked ok. My conclusion is that calling `super().__init__(pin)` did not work well. Did I do something wrong?

BTW I don't think that it is relevant, but my hardware is Seeed XIAO RP2040

###### my problematic implementation:

```
class PinC(DigitalInOut):
    OUT = Direction.OUTPUT

    def __init__(self, pin, mode=Direction.OUTPUT):
        super().__init__(pin)
        self.direction = mode

    def on(self):
        self.value = True

    def off(self):
        self.value = False

    def read(self):
        return self.value
```

###### This class works as expected - without inheritance:

```
class PinC:
    OUT = Direction.OUTPUT

    def __init__(self, pin, mode=Direction.OUTPUT):
        self.dio = DigitalInOut(pin)
        self.dio.direction = mode

    def on(self):
        self.dio.value = True

    def off(self):
        self.dio.value = False

    def read(self):
        return self.dio.value
```

I'd be glad to find out what is the root cause for this!